# Use importXML from column of URLs with arrayformula returning same duplicated result in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I have succeeded in using ImportXML to get the title of the Youtube videos with URLs in Google Sheets. Here is my code:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A3:A),"",IMPORTXML(A3:A, "//*[@id='eow-title']"))
```

However, when I tried to apply ArrayFormula in ImportXML, it returned the result of the first column, over and over again.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(A3:A),"",IMPORTXML(A3:A, "//*[@id='eow-title']")))
```

Like the following image: (Please have a look at column D)

[image: Duplicated results for every rows]

I expect the output of column D could automatically calculate and return the correct title of different Youtube URLs from column A.

any suggestion would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately, that won't do because `ARRAYFORMULA` does not support `IMOPRTXML` formulas. you could try to look up some scripted workaround for this task or give up on one cell solution

---

**2024 UPDATE:**

```
=BYROW(A3:A, LAMBDA(x, IF(ISBLANK(x),,IMPORTXML(x, "//*[@id='eow-title']"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0XzeSrif_I1Q/?hl=sv

ARRAYFORMULA does not support IMOPRTXML, IMPORTHTML.

I use:

```
=iferror(IMPORTXML(A3,"//*[@id='eow-title']"),"") + @CTRL-C @CTRL-V
```