# Automatically Generating Word Definition from Merriam-Webster Dictionary

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to modify this formula to automatically provide the definition in Column B when a word is entered in Column A. Currently, the formula looks like this...

```
=(index(split(concatenate(importxml("https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/"&$A2,"//span[@class='dtText']")),": ",FALSE,TRUE),1,1))
```

This works, but it doesn't automatically provide the definition when adding new words. I tried modifying the formula using an arrayformula (seen below), but it repeats the definition for the word in A2.

```
={"Definition";arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,index(split(concatenate(importxml("https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/"&$A2:A,"//span[@class='dtText']")),": ",FALSE,TRUE),1,1)))}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks for your help. Here's the link to the Google Sheet below so you can edit it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_OrJwlOHxVXZBKA0GFaiXnRS1x5OCszrR9m3UlMuWRY/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

According to this similar article about ***[Use importXML from column of URLs with arrayformula returning same duplicated result in google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55668344)***:

> unfortunately, that won't do because `ARRAYFORMULA` does not support `IMOPRTXML` formulas. you could try to look up some scripted workaround for this task or give up on one cell solution

### Alternative Solution

Perhaps you can use this sample `onEdit(e)` simple trigger script below instead via Apps Script that is bound to your Spreadsheet file:

> Follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#google_sheets) on how to add the script as a bound script in your Spreadsheet file:

### Sample Script:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.range.getColumn() != 1 || e.range.getRow() == 1) return; //ignore if you have not put the word on column A or Col #1 & on row 1
  sh.getRange("B"+e.range.getRow()).setFormula("=(index(split(concatenate(importxml(\"https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/"+e.range.getValue()+"\",\"//span[@class='dtText']\")),\": \",FALSE,TRUE),1,1))");
  if(e.range.getValue() == "") sh.getRange("B"+e.range.getRow()).clear(); //clear column B row if the adjacent word on column A gets deleted
}
```

### Sample Demonstration

- Input the words `crystal` & `believe` on cells `A2` & `A3`

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, ok. Thanks, @irvin-jay-g. I was hoping to accomplish it without a script, but thank you so much for your time in helping me figure this out. Appreciate it!

Comment: @user14915635 I see. Your welcome. You may also want to click the up-vote button on the left. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can have an answer & they'll easily see this post on their searches.